# custom dropdown only displayed selected value Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dropdown

I using custom dropdown using `div`,when I got object response `cards` from API, I need to iterate data using custom dropdown, problem is after selected, the next clicked dropdown only show selected value ( supposed to be array object), this is what I had tried:

**ts file**

```
  selectSavedCard() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  selectDropdownCard(card) {
    this.myData.cards.find((item) => item.cardId === card.id) ?
    this.myData.cards = this.myData.cards.filter((item) => item.cardId === card.id) :
    this.myData.cards= [card];
    this.show = false;
    this.hasSelected = true;
    this.selectedCard = card;
    this.show1 = true;
  }
```

**html file**

```
  <div class="div1" (click)="selectSavedCard()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard" ngDefaultControl>
    <div *ngIf='!hasSelected'>
      <div>
        <p>dropdown</p>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- to bind selected card -->
<ng-container *ngIf="show1">
      <div  *ngFor="let card of myData.cards">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.cardNumberMasked}}  dropdown</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
  </div>

    <div class="div2" *ngIf="show">
    <div *ngFor="let card of myData.cards" (click)="selectDropdownCard(card)">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.cardNumberMasked}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr4zjf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayment%2Fpayment.component.html), for the first clicked dropdown, it worked well (it show all array) after selected card, clicked drodpdown, (it only show selected card, supposed to be show all array), hope can make u guys understand and give me suggestion to solve this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate What you are trying to achieve here

Comment: using custom dropdown, I try to get selected value, then after the second attempt I try, the dropdown only show for the selected value only (supposed to be show all the value )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have filtered and modified `this.myData.cards` to have only one item:

```
 selectDropdownCard(card) {
     this.myData.cards= [card];
  }
```

Therefore it displays only single item.

To push the selected item, you don't need to modify `myData` , you can simply display it without for loop.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show1">
    {{selectedCard.cardNumberMasked}} dropdown
</ng-container>
```

Removing `this.myData.cards= [card];` will display all items

[Forked Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swuekd?embed=1&file=src/app/payment/payment.component.html)

Comment: yeah, but another problem happen, if I removed this.myData.cards= [card]; , then selected card will not push, it will push all the cards

Comment: Where do you want to push selected card? your question wasn't clear

Comment: from dropdown, get selected value and display it on dropdown default component,

Comment: Check the demo I shared, do you want like this?

Comment: Sure. Check it.